# Does a file have to be updated in some way for Java?

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner, printwriter

So I start with a textfile; this textfile at the start contains a number 3 (amount of woningen) 3 Woningen. I can read them with a Scanner without errors. I can also add a Woning without errors. If a Woning is added, the number on top of the file is incremented with 1.

Problem is as follows:
If a Woning has been added, the file has changed. The number is now 4, and a Woning has been added. However, if I want to read all the Woningen, Java returns an exception on the 4th Woning. So for some reason I can't read the 4th Woning.

What can be the cause of this? Do I have to save the file somehow after changes have been made to the file? Or something else has to be done?

Help is greatly appreciated :)!

### EDIT

Note: Woning is the dutch word for House.
Code to read the file:

```
public static Portefeuille read (String infile) {
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (new File(infile));
        ArrayList<Woning> wlijst = new ArrayList<Woning>();
        Portefeuille p = new Portefeuille();
        int woningen = sc.nextInt();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < woningen) {
            sc.nextLine();
            String tag = sc.nextLine();

            wlijst.add(Woning.read(sc));
            wlijst.get(i).setTag(tag);
            //System.out.println(wlijst.get(i).getTag());
            //System.out.println(wlijst.toString());
            p.voegToe(wlijst.get(i));
            i++;
        }
        sc.close();
        return p;
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Portefeuille: Exception is caught");
        Portefeuille p = new Portefeuille();
        return p;
    }   
}
```

Code to write to the file:

```
public static void writeToFile (Portefeuille port, int woningen) {
    try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Makelaar.txt", false)))) {
        woningen = woningen + 1;
        out.println(woningen);
        ArrayList<Woning> wlijst = new ArrayList<Woning>();
        wlijst = port.woninglijst;
        for (int i = 0; i < wlijst.size(); i++) {
            if (wlijst.get(i) instanceof KoopWoning) {
                KoopWoning kw = (KoopWoning) wlijst.get(i);
                KoopWoning.writeToFileK(kw, out);
            }
            else {
                HuurWoning hw = (HuurWoning) wlijst.get(i);
                HuurWoning.writeToFileH(hw, out);                   
            }
        }
        out.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("writeToFile: Exception Caught");
    }
}
```

File looks like this:

```
3
TE KOOP:
Emmalaan 23
3051JC Rotterdam
7 kamers
koopprijs 300000
energiepeil C
VERKOCHT:
Emmalaan 25
3051JC Rotterdam
5 kamers
vraagprijs 280000
energiepeil A
TE HUUR:
Javastraat 88
4078KB Eindhoven
3 kamers
huurprijs 500
```

Comment: You did not show any code, nor did you show the file before and after the change. We can only guess ...

Comment: This sounds really weird. What the heck is a woning?

Comment: I find this question quite hilarious.

Comment: Posting your code and an example of your text file would help us understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I put some code in. I don't understand all those harsh replies honestly. It's not *compulsory* to include code. My question was not really specific to my own code. It was a general question: Do you have to do something with a file youre reading from and writing too. Hope the code helps, and that you can help me with it

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what woningen is. But as far as I know, after adding the data to file, close the file and then try to read the data in file. This definition is always stuck in my mind that one should close the file after you've the finished your process. I can only guess whether you've done two java class for reading and writing or in a same class of writing and reading methods. Hereafter provide some codes so that all can atleast understand on what you're asking.